# Copy Contents of Recovery Pen drive to HDD

Tags: windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive

So, I bought a laptop with Win 8.1
I Created a recovery Drive using a 8 GB pendrive I had.
So My doubt is:
1. Does this recovery is like a Factory reset? I mean without the softwares I installed?
2. Can I copy the contents of Pendrive to My PC (Not the laptop, of course) and recopy it to pendrive when I need it?(I mean does it cause any error in recovery)

Comment: The recovery pen only contains WinRE.  This same environment is also exists on a partition on your HDD.  Neither can be used to install Windows 8.1 only repair, refresh, or set it.

Comment: @Ramhound, So, The thing will work even if it is recopied from PC? Its not bootable. Right? And if so, how can I re-install windows if need? Its genuine.

Comment: Contact laptop manufacturer for recovery discs.